# Gnuplot: fixed colors on a palette

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to plot a 3D-function at differents times, but I need the colors to be the same always.

For instance, at t=0.1s the maximum value at the graphic is 1.3 and I need that value to be red, but at t=0.5s the maximun is 1.1, then that value is going to be the red one now.

What I need is that the 1.3 value to be red always, 1.1 always to be orange and 0.4 always to be yellow, no matter what the max and min values are.

Could anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `set cbrange`...

Answer (score -1):

It is more helpful if you show a minimal plotting commands that show what you are trying to do. For now, you can try using pm3d. It is an splot style for drawing palette-mapped 3d data sets.

```
set pm3d
set palette defined (0.4 "yellow", 1.1 "orange", 1.3 "red")
splot (Your Function) with pm3d
```

Comment: The number in `set palette defined` are relative numbers, which are mapped to the actual cbrange by gnuplot

Comment: No, the actual data range is not from 0.4 to 1.3, so you must add `set cbrange [0.4:1.3]` to your code.